# Interaction Log does not show on opening a subtab

Tags: visualforce

I have a custom visualforce page that opens a Contact in a sub tab using the openSubtab function in the Console Integration API.

I have the Interaction Log enabled for Contacts, however it is not displayed when this sub tab is opened.

This is my visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="PopPageController">
    <script src="/support/console/29.0/integration.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var subTabFunc = function(id) {
            sforce.console.openSubtab(id, '/{!ContactId}', true, 'Tab title', null);
        };

        sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(
            function(result) {
                 subTabFunc(result.id);
            }
        );
    </script>    
</apex:page>
```

Is there some restriction on when the Interaction Log will be displayed?